# Get attention on a question

Tags: discussion, questions

What is the best way to get more attention an a question?

In my questions, I try to be very specific and precise, add tags, add all my trials, my thoughts, updated my progress etc. I even tried to set a bounty, but on my most visited question I only got 98 Views in 1 Month.

I don't have a big network or a lot of follower on social media sites.

In my opinion few visits means 1) a bad title 2) wrong/no tags.

I there a "best practice" for creating Titles?

**Edit:** wouldn't it be funny if this post don't get enough attention :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some good, but very specialized questions. If there are not many people who know an answer, attention alone does not help you. I don't see anything in particular that you did "wrong".

A **bounty** *can* help to draw attention and even motivate users to dig into the problem themselves if they don't know the answer yet.

Also, **tags** are not to be underestimated. For example I subscribed to a few tags where I have a good amount of knowlegde and get daily emails about new questions on these tags. So choosing tags carefully can help to draw attention of the right people. Use relevant but not too specific tags (Hint: you see the number of followers if you hover over a tag)

Comment: the "hover over a tag" tip is pretty nifty, thank you :) I just looked at my used tags and there are only ~100 follower combined. I try to add/replace the tags with more frequented tags. I wouldn't have a problem to start a bounty with 300 reputations, but unfortunately this is not a guarantee to get a answer. And that's absolute ok, but on the other side it would be sad if my reputations are gone without getting a answer.

Answer (score 1):

On top of Fabian's great answer, you can also use the **share functionality to draw attention** on Facebook, Twitter using the #magento or #realmagento hashtag

Answer (score -1):

Don't feel badly.  In my experience, it's tough to get attention on this site for two reasons:

1. Magento is a deeply complected piece of software, so it's tough to answer questions based on small code samples.
2. There really aren't a lot of experts here.  There seems to be a dozen or so guys who really get it and the rest of us just flounder our way though this platform.

**EDIT:** I see I'm getting downvoted here for the second part of my answer.  But I'm going to leave this answer here because it is *absolutely true*.  Go look at the [all-time users on the Magento SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) and compare it to the [all-time users on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=all).  There are exactly 13 people on Magento SE with a reputation of 10K or higher.  You can go *more than 10 pages deep* on the regular SO users list and still not find someone with a reputation below 100K. I'm not saying that you can't get helpful answers from people with reps under 10K, but it does support my claim that "there really aren't a lot of experts here".

Comment: I agree with #1, but not with #2. I think there are a lot of experts. But like @fschmengler mentioned a lot of questions are very specialized.

Comment: You get so many good answers here for your problems. The bigger problem is that users don't describe problems specific enough sometimes and just want others to write code for them without even trying.

Comment: @Pawel, you may *think* there are a lot of experts but you might reconsider in light of actual data.  Please see my edit.

Comment: I really get your point, but in my opinion there is no correlation between the reputations and if someone is a expert or not.

Comment: Also, voting culture is different than on SO, so it's harder to get to 100k here than there, even if you subtract out the fact that SO is around for a few more years and the audience is larger.